# Scala Array Generics vs Vector Generics

Tags: arrays, scala, generics, vector, types

So I have been working on a refactor in my project to convert `Vector`'s in my code to `Array`'s. The reason being that my application needs to be very performant, and using while-iterations on `Array`'s is significantly faster than for comprehensions and iterations on `Vector`'s. (see [this blog post for details](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html#foreach-performance))

However I have run into an issue I can't seem to easily find an answer for. I have tweaked my code to hide implementation details, and just boil down to the code needed to highlight the issue.

The following class structure, when using `Vector`, compiles totally fine:

```
sealed abstract class BaseClass {    
  def element: Int
}

sealed abstract class TypeA extends BaseClass {
  def element = 2
  def children: Vector[BaseClass]
}

case class TypeB(element: Int = 2) extends BaseClass
case class TypeAA(children: Vector[TypeA]) extends TypeA
case class TypeAB(children: Vector[TypeB]) extends TypeA
```

Now, when switching from using `Vector` to using `Array`, it no longer compiles:

```
sealed abstract class BaseClass {
  def element: Int
}

sealed abstract class TypeA extends BaseClass {
  def element = 2
  def children: Array[BaseClass]
}

case class TypeB(element: Int = 2) extends BaseClass
case class TypeAA(children: Array[TypeA]) extends TypeA
case class TypeAB(children: Array[TypeB]) extends TypeA
```

I get the error: `overriding method children in class TypeA of type => Array[BaseClass]; value children has incompatible type` for both TypeAA and TypeAB classes.

I have a feeling I need to do an implicit conversion somewhere, but I am relatively new to Scala (only a couple months) and am not sure exactly how to use it.

Sorry if this has been asked elsewhere, I had trouble finding the correct search terms for the issue i am having.

Comment: The problem is that `Array` is invariant in Scala while `Vector` is covariant. This means that `Vector[TypeA]` is a subtype of `Vector[BaseClass]`, but `Array[TypeA]` is not a subtype of `Array[BaseClass]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `_ <: BaseClass` instead of using the generic type itself:

```scala
sealed abstract class TypeA extends BaseClass {
  def element = 2
  def children: Array[_ <: BaseClass]
}
```

This happens because the generic type parameter in `Array` is invariant, while in `Vector` it is covariant:

```scala
final class Array[T]
final class Vector[+A]
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I went through the question in a rush. The problem is with generic types - you should use an upper bound to achieve that.

Comment: yes your revision works as expected, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the fact `Vector[+A]` is covariant in its type parameter `A` while `Array[A]` is not, meaning invariant in `A`

You can work around that fact using [F-Bounded Polymorphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification):

```
sealed abstract class TypeA[A :< Type[A]] extends BaseClass {
  def children: Array[A] 
}
case class TypeAA(children: Array[TypeA]) extends TypeA[TypeA]
case class TypeAB(children: Array[TypeB]) extends TypeA[TypeB]
```

Comment: thank you! I tried to upvote but could not due to account restrictions. I accepted Andrei answer as he was first. thanks for the help though!